# setOnItemClickListner affecting multiple views of ListView?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

ListView contains more than one string.

1. data source for adapter is List of Strings
2. resource for adapter is textview

   ```
   view.appointmentTime.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

               ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(lastClicked)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

               ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(lastClicked)).setTextSize(18f);

               ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00BBE4"));

               ((TextView) view).setTextSize(22f);

               lastClicked = position;

               getBookAppointment().setApptTime((getLong_timings().get(position) / 1000));

           }

       });
   ```

   My initial adapter was :

   public class AppointmentTimingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
       Context context;

   ```
   public AppointmentTimingAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<AppointmentTime> objects) {
       super(context, resource, objects);
       this.context = context;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       return AppointmentTimeView.newInstance((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
               , parent, ScheduleView.getTimings().get(position));
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: set this attribute to textView:  android:focusable="false" in your xml file.

Comment: I don't exactly get what you want, but from my experience, directly altering views in a list view is not a good thing. Alternatively, change the data model and then make a `notifyDataSetChanged()` call to the adapter. Your data model seems to be just a `String`. Change that to a class of your definition that holds additional information about other changeable attributes (text color, size).

Comment: Thats what i was doing initially but in that case there is lag between when i click on the view and when the color changes

Comment: Without code it's hard to guess. But a lag makes me doubt that a "lengthy" operation was being done in the `getView` method of the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: no longer looks like a View recycling issue - the `convertView` parameter (the potentially recycled view) in `getView()` implementation seems to be ignored.

---

Without **any** information as to the symptoms you're seeing which makes you think there is an error, I would suspect you've been hit by View recycling.

You set these attributes on the clicked view, then scroll, and suddenly another view looks like it has been clicked, even though it's not been clicked. This view has been reused or recycled.

You can avoid these errors by not modifying views directly in your ListView. Modify the dataset / store the "selected" items in a list and refresh the ListView (adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()), and use the selected items list to determine when to apply different styling.

- [set text in textview of a list item on click of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299911/set-text-in-textview-of-a-list-item-on-click-of-button/31300420#31300420)
- [Styling item Views in Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834606/styling-item-views-in-android-listview/30834871#30834871)

Comment: If i do it using notifyDataSetChanged() there is lag,change are not that instantaneous

Comment: maybe you can add your adapter to your question. I've used notifyDataSetChanged in all my adapters so far with no lag, so perhaps there is an optimisation to be had.

Comment: @user3448010 the first link I provide is a complete working example where the adapter is backed by a dataset that is modified on click - as you can see in the GIF, there is no lag, so you might be able to use that codebase (the code was written solely for this reason, it's very bare) as an example.

Comment: @user3448010 not as a comment, please, edit your question. No one can read that.

Comment: The source of `AppointmentTimeView.newInstance` should be also posted. However, from its name I guess that you're wasting the view reuse opportunity.

Comment: and ScheduleView.getTimings() - that value I suppose is being updated - where, by who? It no longer looks like a view recycling issue as you create a new view each time (which is a separate, unrelated issue).